# Dependence between summation and difference of normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose $x,y$ i.i.d. with distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma ^2) $. Then $z=x+y$ and $w=x-y$. The marginal distribution for $z\text{ and }w$ is  $\mathcal{N}(0,2\sigma ^2)$. How can we prove that $w$ and $z$ are independent or not independent?

Comment: $z$ and $w$ are uncorrelated, but what about dependence? My intuition is that they are independent but i cant prove it so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We define the vector  $U=(z,w)$.

Let $(\lambda$, $\beta) \in \mathbb{R^2}$,  we have that $\lambda z+\beta w=(\lambda+\beta)x+(\lambda-\beta)y$, therefore U is a Gaussian vector because x and y are independent and normally distributed, hence $\lambda z+\beta w$ is Gaussian too.

The independence can be proved by showing that $z$ and $w$ are uncorrelated.
$cov(z,w)=var(x)-var(y)$, and because $var(x)=var(y)$, we can conclude that z and w are independent.

Comment: Does $\lambda z + \beta w $ is gaussian imply $U$ is gaussian ? (so $z$ and $w$ are jointly gaussian ?) It is not clear to me, am i missing something?

Comment: A vector $X=(X_1,X_2)$ is Gaussian if and only if all linear combinations of its element are normally distributed. That is why I picked a $\lambda$ and $\beta$ to prove that all linear combinations is normally distributed.

Comment: thank you, I found a different approach there by user Ken Dunn. Thank you so much tho.

Comment: Please note that $cov(z,w)=0$ implies independence of $z$ and $w$ only when $z$ and $w$ are normally distributed. In general that covariance equals zero does imply independence of two random variables.